# Why does my href only work after I manually refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

I made a table filled with SQL data. I added a data-href to the table rows, which brings me to another page and shows all the data from that row. But this only works after I manually refresh the page my table is on. When I enter the page using normal hrefs, clicking the table row doesn't do anything. When I refresh my page using the page refresher next to the URL bar, the table row event works. What is the cause of this?

```
<script>
    var trid;
    function foo() {
    }
</script>
<script>
    $(function(){       
        $('*[data-href]').click(function(){
            window.location = $(this).data('href');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

This code above is located in the page head

```
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="stoftest.php">Stoftest</a></li>
        <li><a href="overzicht.php">Overzicht</a></li>
        <li><a href="klim.php">Klimopdracht</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Code above is the reference to the page with the table (middle one).

```
echo "<table>"; 
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>".'Stof'."</th>";
echo "<th>".'Score'."</th>";
echo "<th>".'Datum'."</th>";
echo "</tr>";
foreach ($result as $pers) {
    echo "<tr data-href='detail.php?persId=".$pers->id."'>";
    echo "<td>".$pers->stofid."</td>
    <td>".$pers->zoeken."</td>
    <td>".$pers->datum."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Code above is my table using PHP and HTML

All of this only works after a manual page refresh. I have no clue what causes this problem. I even tried a automatic page refresh when I enter this page, but this refresh event only works after I manually refresh the page.

Tell me if you need any more code.

Comment: better use a class, and call .classname.on click, on works like live,

Comment: Perhaps the page is `caching`. If you're using chrome try ensuring you have cache disabled in network tab of the developer tools or go into "incognito mode" and see if the error still persists.

Comment: the error still persists, i tried incognito mode

Comment: I also tried it on my phone, and it also doesnt work on there

Comment: any other options?

Comment: Enable the error logs. When your script hangs what does it say? There should be an error somewhere.

Comment: You don't mention, but do you use jQuery? https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ mentions "A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." Also, look in how you can put a breakpoint in the development tools in your browser on your code and make sure it is even executed. Check the console output for errors. This should help you to track it down.

Comment: Duplicate of your own previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370503/ Please do not create such duplicates, but follow up on the responses you get to your original version of the question. (And if those don’t come immediately, then show a bit of _patience_!) If you have relevant new info to add, then please _edit_ your existing question, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My table row action doesnt work unless I manually refresh the page. How to fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370503/my-table-row-action-doesnt-work-unless-i-manually-refresh-the-page-how-to-fix-t)

Comment: deleted my prev question, yes i use jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your click handler is fine so the issue must lie elsewhere in the page.

Opening your Javascript console and adding some console.log calls can be helpful. e.g.

```
$('*[data-href]')
  .each(function()
  {
    // Check this value the first time the page loads
    // then see if it changes when the page reloads
    console.log($(this).data('href'));
  })
  .click(function(event)
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).data('href');
  });
```